# How to convert date format in file

Tags: date, csv

**Input file:**  Contains 3 columns with the 3rd column is date in `DD-MMM-YYYY` format
sample data:

```
1232,abdc, 02-Jan-2014
4534,kdafh, 20-Feb-2014
364,asjhdk, 11-Jul-2012
```

**required output:**

```
1232,abdc, 2014-01-02
4534,kdafh, 2014-02-20
364,asjhdk, 2012-07-11
```

using function date: `date -d 20-DEC-2014 +%Y-%m-%d` 
 used it awk command gives error

 Is there any other way?

Comment: How shall we help you if you don't tell us the exact command you used (and the error message)?

Answer (score 4):

One possible answer using awk, assuming the input file is input-file.txt and output file is output-file.txt :

```
awk -F ',' '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2);system("date -d "$3" +%Y-%m-%d");}' input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Comment: The input file has a time stamp in the date field so the about code is give error. So input file has changed as below,1232,abdc, 02-Jan-2014 18:01:37</br>
4534,kdafh, 20-Feb-2014 07:17:19</br>
364,asjhdk, 11-Jul-2012 23:20:30</br>

Comment: @user_tmo The input field does _not_ have a timestamp in the input field.  This is evident from the text in the question.  If it as, and if you are the original user, then please update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to clean up the excessive whitespace in the header-less CSV input and then rewrite the 3rd field.  The 3rd field is rewritten by parsing the given date using `strptime()` with the time format string `%d-%b-%Y` and then reformatting the resulting Unix timestamp using `strftime()` and the `%F` formatting string (you could use, e.g., `%Y-%m-%d` in place of `%F`):

```bash
mlr --csv -N \
    clean-whitespace then \
    put '$3 = strftime(strptime($3,"%d-%b-%Y"),"%F")' file
```

Given the data in the question, this would output

```
1232,abdc,2014-01-02
4534,kdafh,2014-02-20
364,asjhdk,2012-07-11
```

If your data has a timestamp in the same field, you may tweak the format strings used in the `strptime()` and `strftime()` calls to suit your needs.

See the manual for `strftime` on your system to see what these formatting strings mean and what your options for formatting dates and times are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you input text is like this:

```
1232,abdc, 02-Jan-2014 18:01:37</br> 
4534,kdafh, 20-Feb-2014 07:17:19</br>
364,asjhdk, 11-Jul-2012 23:20:30</br>
```

my answer would become:

```
cat input-file.txt | sed 's[</br>[[g' | awk -F ',' '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2);system("date -d \""$3" "$4"\" +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"");}' > output-file.txt
```

And if the records are on a single line (no new line in input file after the </br>, it woukd be

```
cat input-file.txt | sed 's[</br>[\n[g' | awk -F ',' '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2);system("date -d \""$3" "$4"\" +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"");}' > output-file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to fork a new process that executes a shell and another command for every line of a file, that would be very inefficient. Having a shell interpret code based on input is also a recipe for introducing command injection vulnerabilities. Further more, that `-d` option is non-standard.

Here, I'd use a text processing tool that can do time manipulation such as perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
  s{\d+-\w+-\d+$}{Time::Piece->strptime($&, "%d-%b-%Y")->ymd}e
  ' < your-file
```

There, we match on `<digits>-<word-characters>-<digits>` found at the end of the line (`$`), interpret that as `<day>-<month-abbrev>-<year>` and reformat as `<yead>-<month>-<day>` using perl's core Time::Piece module.